# Python regex is taking more time

Tags: python, regex

I want to get complete line after first occurrence of the delimiter char I am using below regex but it is taking hell lot of time to parse

```
import re
  
str = "abc:dad:kdl--sa:dajs: idsa:kd"
mypat = re.compile(r'.+?:(.+)')
result = mypat.search(str)
line = result.group(1)
line = line.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
  
print (line)
```

Comment: Try it with `[^:]+:(.+)`

Comment: did you try `string.split(':')`?

Comment: It takes a total of about 170 microseconds. I don't call that "hell lot of time". Either some context is missing, or you're living on a different timescale.

Comment: Addendum to @wombatz comment: you probably want to use the `maxsplit` parameter: `str.split(':', maxsplit=1)[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to get complete line after first occurrence of the delimiter char"*

```
first_occurence = line.index(DELIMITER)
line_after = line[first_occurence+1:]
```

Note: will raise the `ValueError` if the DELIMITER is not present.